# : [WARNING]Mismatch of Datatypes Source Document. yotpo_rich_snippets. Fields: review_count

Tags: magento2.3.4, magento1.9.2.3, data-migration-tool

During the data migration from Magento `1.9.2.3` to magento `2.3.4` with data migration tool, this warning is displayed.

Not sure if it is to be ignored or looked into. Please help me get to the root cause of this warning.

```
 [WARNING]Mismatch of Datatypes Source Document. yotpo_rich_snippets. Fields: review_count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code you write your source code tag in `map.xml` file. i am not sure but may be help this code

```
<ignore>
    <document>yotpo_rich_snippets.review_count</document>
</ignore>
```

Any query let me know..

thanks.

Comment: I understand this code helps ignore this particular field. Is there a way to correct the data type so both source and the destination have the same data type?

Comment: Yes same code but sorce and destination tag add your error

Comment: got it. will do as advised.